# Moving folders to a directory according to their name

Tags: python

I'm new in Python and am currently developing an application that moves folders to a specific directory according their folder name.

I get no errors nor warnings but the application won't move the folders.
Here's the code:

```
import os
import shutil

def shorting_algorithm():

    file_list = []
    directory = input("Give the directory you want to search.")
    newdir = "D:\\Torrents\\Complete\\Udemy"
    name = "'" + input("Give the name of the files you want to move.") + "'"
    xlist = os.listdir(directory)
    print(xlist)
    print(name)


    for files in xlist:
        if name in files:
            shutil.move(directory + files,newdir)


shorting_algorithm()
```

Note: I tried removing "'" +...+"'" but it didn't work either. Any ideas?

Comment: Note that `name` is going to be one big string if you input multiple files in that field. Try moving a single file first in combination with the `os.path.join` as in the answer below,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't forget the file separator while joining the file and the directory.

```
for files in xlist:

    #if name in files: EDIT: As pointed out by IosiG, Change here too
    if name == files:
        shutil.move(directory + files,newdir) #make changes here

directory + '\\' + files. 
#or 
import os
os.path.join(directory,files)
```

Comment: Tried both of them and still the same, the application runs normally without errors or warning but the folders won't move.

Comment: try it with the name as a normal input, no need for `'+...+'` portion. Make sure you are providing just 1 name at a time. Does it still not work? The code should work this way, there may be other issues that we cant detect from what you have provided us. @iHate2

Comment: The changes i made:

for files in xlist:
        if name in files:
            shutil.move(directory + '\\' + files,newdir)

Comment: The problem is not that, but that he's looping through the files and then looking if the name of the file to be moved is "in" the name of a file.

Comment: oof. Good spot. @IosiG Go ahead write that as an answer

Comment: Turns out that was the problem, i made it normal input and it moved the folders fine. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the for loop or the if statement.  You already identified the file in the main code block.  Since you are specifying a directory and a filename explicitly, you don't need to do a loop through a directory list to find one.  That's more for when you want a program to automatically find a file that fits some particular condition. Try this:

```
    import os
    import shutil

    def shorting_algorithm():

            directory = input("Give the directory you want to search.")
            newdir = r'D:\Torrents\Complete\Udemy'
            name = "\\" + input("Give the name of you files you want to move.")
            print(name)
            print(directory)
            shutil.move(directory + name,newdir)

    shorting_algorithm()
```

Getting rid of the extra quotes and adding your slashes to the path, turning your newdir into a raw string to avoid escapes, and getting rid of the for loop should make this code work.  I just tested it out and it works here.

Comment: The loop is used to check if the file to be moved is actually on the directory before performing the move. I agree that it would work without that as well, but it's actually a good practice to check to user input before using it.

Comment: @losiG That makes sense.  In this case it doesn't really do that though.  There are no error messages or exception catches in the loop so I figured that if you weren't going to include an `else: print("No such directory.")` or something, there was no reason for the loop to be there. Perhaps I should have stated that...It's kind of an important caveat lol. :/

Comment: name ""xlist" is not defined"

Comment: Oh yeah.  My bad.  I deleted it because you don't need xlist anymore if you aren't looping through a list, but I forgot to remove the `print` statement.  Editing now.  Actually, you can go ahead and drop file_list too.  Of course, all this assumes you don't intend to put any exception handling into this that may need the loop.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your loop, you mixed two ways of iterating.
What happens is the following:

```
for files in xlist: #loop through the names of the files
    if name in files: # look for the name of your file inside the name of another file
        shutil.move(directory + files,newdir)
```

What should be done is the following:

```
    if name in xlist:
        shutil.move(directory + name,newdir)
```

or also

```
for file in xlist: # only reason for this is if you want input check 
    if str(file) == name:
       # do whatever you need
```

Also, you **have** to remove the `"'" +...+"'"` from the input, since you are entering those into the string, which will make the comparison quite messy.
I'd recommend also to use raw_input instead of input.

Comment: The "files" variable contains one folder name per loop and  checks each folder separately and moves it accordingly. Without the loop, the files variable doesn't exist so i get an error. With the loop and if name in xlist:
        shutil.move(directory + files,newdir) i get "expected an indented block" error. I think the loop is essential because it acts sort of like "referense".

Comment: You don't need to save the file name in the 'files' variable since you already have the 'name' variable. The loop is good if you want to check the input, but then you would have to check if name == str(files)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your answers, the problem was easily solved by using "shutil.move(directory + '\' + files,newdir)" as suggested.

```
import os
import shutil

def shorting_algorithm():
    directory = input("Give the directory you want to search.")
    name = input("Give the name of you files you want to move.")
    newdir = input("Give the new directory.")
    xlist = os.listdir(directory)    

    for files in xlist:
        if name in files:
          shutil.move(directory + '\\' + files,newdir)                 

shorting_algorithm()
```